# Force MikTex to produce auxiliary files

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files

I recently moved to a new computer and have noticed that since installing the latest version of Miktex, compiling my documents no longer produces any auxiliary files whatsoever. The files that I used to see but are no longer generated are the .aux files, .bbl files (for BibTex), .log files, .out files, .thm files and .toc files. There is nothing other than the .pdf and synctex.gz file.

Despite this the pdf displays as usual. This would not bother me otherwise, but I can no longer upload to the arxiv no longer works correctly due to the missing auxiliary files. I am wondering if there is a way to force MikTex to produce the missing files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Normally your TeX compiler should produce the aux files. Do you maybe use an editor that moves the auxiliary files into their own subdirectory or cleans aux files after successful compilation?

Comment: This is impossible if it compiles... I can only suppose your MiKTeX system is configured so the auxiliary files go to some subdirectory. Which editor do you use?

Comment: MikTeX option `-output-directory` allows you to send all output files to another folder, but the `pdf` result is also an output file then it should be also hidden. Are you sure that auxiliary files don't exist? Did you look with a `dir` command from a `cmd` window?

Comment: For some reason I am not able to comment on my question so I will try to leave this as an "answer" for now. I am using version 0.6.1 of TexWorks (MikTex 2.9.6300 64-bit). Typing dir in cmd window confirms that there are no aux files. I have no idea how it manages to compile (and this has not been an issue on any other computer I've used). Thanks.

Comment: @Ignasi: there's also the `-aux-directory` switch.

Comment: I suggest you try with another editor. B.t.w. `TeXworks` has now moved to versio n 0.6.2. You should begin with updating, just in case. Do you see the .log file in TeX works console when you compile?

Comment: @Bernard Good point, it looks like there is a new version of MikTex as well. I'll try that first...

Comment: Wild guess: You are using `texify --clean ...`  to compile. This will remove auxiliary files after the compilation.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I tried a new installation of MikTex in a new folder and it still doesn't produce anything but pdf and synctex. I'll try a different editor.

Comment: Switching to TexStudio solved my problem. I guess this can be closed although I still have no idea why Texworks does this for me.

Comment: @user149719 then you should make an effort and try to find it out. It can't be so difficult to check the configuration of your compilation call in texworks and check if there is some switch that looks as if it does some cleaning up.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

Using @Ulrike_Fischer's suggestion I edited "pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX" in `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Typesetting` and found that --clean was indeed enabled (apparently by default). Deleting this fixed my problem.